# Get-Content: new line

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a script:

```bsh
(Get-Content .\test.xml).replace('VALUE', 'MY_VALUE') | Set-Content .\test.xml
(Get-Content .\test.xml).replace('VALUE_01', 'MY_VALUE_01') | Set-Content .\test.xml
```

When I am seeing result in file:

```
MY_VALUEMY_VALUE_01
```

Is it possible to make new lines some kind like this:

```
MY_VALUE
MY_VALUE_01
```

XML:

```xml
<VALUE>TEST</VALUE><VALUE_01>TEST_1</VALUE_01>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: ('VALUE', 'MY_VALUE\n') maybe ?

Comment: can you provide the test.xml file?

Comment: Hi, I've got result after Invoke-WebRequest in one line <VALUE>TEST</VALUE><VALUE_01>TEST_1</VALUE_01>, but I need after replacing the tags name to make it in two lines

Comment: still, provide a `test.xml`, show us what you want to repalce and what output you expect. Then we can help you.

Comment: Can you not just ignore the second line of code? Replacing VALUE with MY_VALUE works for both VALUE and VALUE_01. You are trying to replace something you have already replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems I found soloution:

```
(get-content .\test.xml) -replace 'VALUE',"`nVALUE_01" | set-content .\test.xml
(get-content .\test.xml) -replace 'VALUE_01',"`nMY_VALUE_01" | set-content .\test.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Found this while trying to get carriage returns when Writing xml to a file. I thought I'd add my solution in case others land here looking for this answer.

The only answer so far is not ideal because it adds extra characters in the tag itself which could have unintended consequences if the xml data is used for anything else.

A better answer, I believe, would be to let powershell treat the xml as xml and use the save method xml objects expose. The save method writes nicely formatted xml.

```
$fileContents = [xml]((Get-Content .\test.xml) -replace "VALUE","VALUE01" )
$fileContents.save(.\test.xml)
```

If you want to do a double replace before saving the file, it looks cumbersome but in essence is just add Another -replace and a surrounding pair of parenthesis.

```
$fileContents = [xml](((Get-Content .\test.xml) -replace "VALUE1","VALUE01" ) -replace "VALUE2","VALUE02")
$fileContents.save(.\test.xml)
```

If you want it as a one liner it could look like this, the second replace is removed for legibility and line length.

```
([xml]((Get-Content .\test.xml) -replace "VALUE","VALUE01" )).save(.\test.xml)
```

I personally think it is better with multiple lines when it starts getting complex to make it easier to read and to modify.